# Prime elements in localisation

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, localization

> **Def:** [$p$ is prime] $\iff$ [$p | ab$ $\Rightarrow$ $(p | a)$ or $(p | b)$]

Assume 
$$S_1(n) := \{n^k | k \geq 0\}$$
$$S_2(n) := \{m \in \mathbb{Z} | (m,n) = 1\}$$

I want to describe all prime elements in localisations $S_1^{-1}\mathbb{Z}$ and $S_2^{-1}\mathbb{Z}$. Which technique can I use here ?

Comment: Those rings are all subrings of $\Bbb{Q}$. So what happens here is that some of the primes of $\Bbb{Z}$ become units. Those that don't, remain primes. So, for each prime number $p$, you need to figure out whether $1/p$ is in the localization or not

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen so in the first case, all prime elements of $\Bbb{Z}$ remain primes in it’s localization, except $\pm n$ if n is prime. In the second case, all primes $p : |p| < n$ will become units. Am i right?

Comment: Not quite. $1/3=2/6$ is in $S_1^{-1}\Bbb{Z}$ when $n=6$. And $1/17\in S_2^{-1}\Bbb{Z}$ when $n=6$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the localization $S_1^{-1} \Bbb Z$, the number $n \in \mathbb Z$ becomes a unit. Now all the factors of $n$ in $\mathbb Z$ become units: Write $n = k \ell$. Then
$$\ell^{-1} = n^{-1} k \in S_1^{-1}\Bbb Z.$$
So all factors of $n$ become units, i.e., the primes in $S_1^{-1}\Bbb Z$ are all primes in $\mathbb Z$ except for the ones that are factors of $n$.

On the other hand, the units in $S_2^{-1} \Bbb Z$ are all numbers that are coprime to $n$. So the primes in $S_2^{-1}$ are the primes in $\mathbb Z$ which are a factor of $n$.

Comment: Thanks, I seem to have lost the ability to track my negations.